# Autosuggest field and variants

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> There is a problem, when i type anything in search field, suggest variants looks weird ( on the picture) because endings is cut. I want to cut down not a single word, but a sentence( first part of suggest ).

```
export const SkillAutoSuggestOption = (
   props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>,
   option: any,
   state: AutocompleteRenderOptionState,
   getName: (option: any) => string
): React.ReactNode => {
   const matches = match(getName(option), state.inputValue, { insideWords: true })
   const parts = parse(getName(option), matches)

   const path = () => {
       if ('skillPathForAutoSuggest' in option) {
           return option.skillPathForAutoSuggest
       } else return getNodePath(option)
   }

   return (
       <ListItem {...props} key={option.skill_id}>
           {option.isCategory && <SCircleIcon />}
           {parts.map((part, index) => (
               <SLabel key={index} style={part.highlight ? { color: tannBlue } : {}}>
                   {part.text}
               </SLabel>
           ))}
           <SSkillPath>{path()}</SSkillPath>
       </ListItem>
   )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the getNodePath, parse and match functions source code/the source library if you use any? The problem is not related to rendering the list part but is related to how these functions work.